# Not being able to fetch the result to log in POST API

Tags: sql, logging, wso2, wso2-micro-integrator

I am trying to do post api request and trying to fetch the data through SQL Query, however, I am unable to understand how to log the results. Any help would mean a lot, the code I have written is below:

```
            <statement>
                <sql><![CDATA[SELECT * FROM TEST2 t WHERE t.CORRELATION_ID = 1]]></sql>
                <result column="CORRELATION_ID" name="CORRELATION_ID"/>
                <result column="MSISDN" name="MSISDN"/>
                <result column="FL" name="FLAG"/>
            </statement>
            <log level="full">
                <property name="After Query" value="Below Query"/>
                <property expression="get-property(FLAG)" name="FLAGG"/>
            </log>
```

I am not getting any value in logs instead it is printing nothing as the value is given as "FLAGG = ".
Thank You

Comment: You are missing the quote inside the get-property() function. Try changing it to get-property('FLAG') and verify if the property is being logged as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get data from the Database the returned values should be assigned to properties. Your Log seems to be a bit off. Can you try the following?

```xml
<log level="full">
  <property name="After Query" value="Below Query"/>
  <property expression="$ctx:FLAG" name="FLAGG"/>
  <property expression="$ctx:CORRELATION_ID" name="CORRELATION_ID"/>
</log>
```